# Get all task from project using Asana API in php

Tags: php, asana-api

I have to fetch task using Asana API under project, 
I tried so far but gives error

```
$tasksall = $asana->getProjectTasks($projectId);
$tasksJson = json_decode($tasksall);
print_r($taskJson);
```

Call a function

```
public function getProjectTasks($projectId){        
return $this->askAsana($this->taskUrl."?project={$projectId}");
}
```

Comment: `gives error` ... would you mind sharing the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use this as your main part

```
$projectId='Your project id';
$taskbyproject = $asana->getProjectTasks($projectId);
//print_r($taskbyproject);
```

Use this as Function

```
 public function getProjectTasks($projectId, array $opts = array())
    {
        $options = http_build_query($opts);
        return $this->askAsana($this->taskUrl . '?project=' . $projectId . '&' . $options);
    }
```